# Using a custom JPanel but move it with the editor

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I'm trying to draw some custom graphics on a Java Swing application but I'm having trouble with using a custom JPanel class and the graphical editor.

Right now I'm using WindowBuilder Pro (an Eclipse Plugin).

The problem is that I can't see my JPanel (nor edit any of its properties) in the graphical editor if I instance that JPanel as a subclass of JPanel. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
JPanel panel = new CustomPanel();
panel.setBounds(...);
frmApplication.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

That above doesn't work, but if I do instead:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBounds(...);
frmApplication.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

And don't use my custom class, then it works just fine, but of course I can't draw any custom graphics. How should I fix this?

**EDIT**

I just realised that the code generator wasn't able to interpret the custom JPanel because it was an inner class. Making it a separate class solved my problem.

Comment: Why doesn't your CostumPanel attept work? what error do you get?

Comment: No error, it just doesn't show at all in the graphical editor. It's of course shown when running the application.

Comment: Ok, I just realised the problem while writing the whole code. The generator wasn't able to detect the inner class...

Comment: Oh no what a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Step to follow for custom painting on `JPanel`. Please validate with your `CustomPanel` class.

- override `paintComponent()` method
- always call `super.paintComponent(g);` inside overridden `paintComponent` method

> Please have a look at **[Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)** for in-depth discussion on *Performing Custom Painting*.

sample code:

```
class CustomJPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("Hello", 10, 10);
        g.fillRect(20, 20, 50, 50);
    }
}

JPanel panel = new CustomJPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

screenshots:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I'm already doing that in my code. Good to know I'm doing it right anyway.

Comment: You really only need to start with the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the basics, (such as also overriding the getPreferredSize() to return the size of the panel). The other tutorial is more technical and won't help with this issue.

Answer (score -2):

Your CustomPanel should inherit from JPanel.

And in your main:

```
CustomPanel panel = new CustomPanel();
```

Comment: He states that his CustomPanel class already extends from JPanel. His code s not throwing a NPE, and so your answer does not answer the question.